# AHK Произвольно меняет символы

Tags: символы, ahk

Всем привет, код чтобы посылать сообщение в чат дискорд и тг.
При отправке рандомно меняет символы, то напишет вот так Slot_Machine: 6slot_machine: ;Slot-machine; ;Slot_machine: . вообщем сам меняет двоеточие, как законтрить? пробовал менять кодировку, не помогло.

```
WinGet, L, list, BOG - tg

Return
3::Pause
2::
Loop{
SendMessage, 0x06, 1,,,ahk_id 0x10d38
ControlSend, , :slot_machine: {Enter}, ahk_id 0x10d38
Random ranSleep, 10005, 10010                 # random delay       
sleep %ranSleep%
}
Return
```